# How to remove the box with the sample text which appears on key press?

Tags: html

Check out the print screen i have pasted below:

[image]

How to remove the block that appears with previously typed names?
The gray box below it is meant for searching on keyup event.
I dont need the white block to show me the names additionally.
How to get rid of it?

Comment: In what context is this happening? Do you have some code to show?

Comment: When i type any letter in the text box, the box beneath it returns the records starting from that letter on keyup event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `autocomplete="off"` to the `input` element..

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. But i am getting error in the editor saying 'autocomplete' is not allowed at this point. Do you know what that means?

Comment: (*i am asking this because it is an HTML5 attribute, so the editor might not be aware of it yet..*) You might also want to add an HTML5 doctype to your document.. `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Oops sorry... my mistake!!! It does work I was giving the property to the input field with hidden type.... It does work! Thanks a lot! Damn i need more 5 min to click on the 'green' sign...